# Finding sides of rectangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, area

It is given that area of rectangle = its perimeter and the diagonal is 3√5. We are to find it's area by use of quadratic equations. The problem is that I'm getting a 4 degree equation when I substitute for a in the second equation. How do I find the sides of rectangle ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site, then edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let, length$=a$ and weidth $=b$
So,
$$ab=2(a+b)..............(1)$$
$$\text{and,}$$
$$a^2+b^2=(3 \sqrt(5))^2...............(2)$$
From (2) we get,

\begin{array}{ll}
& a^2+b^2 &=(3 \sqrt(5))^2\\
& \implies a^2+b^2 +2ab &=(3 \sqrt(5))^2 +2ab \\
& \implies (a+b)^2 &=45+4(a+b) \\
& \implies (a+b)^2 -4(a+b)-45 &=0 \\
&Let,&\\
& & a+b=p\\
& \implies p^2 -4p-45 &=0 \\
& \implies (p-9)(p+5)&=0 \\
& p=9,-5 &[\text{Here, p=-5 is not possible, because the sum of two lengths can't be negative}]\\
&Hence,&\\
& a+b &=9 \\
& \implies a &=9-b..........(3) 
\end{array}

From equation (1) we get now,

\begin{array}{ll}
& (9-b)b &=2(9-b+b)\\
& \implies b^2-9b+18 &=0 \\
& \implies (b-6)(b-3) &=0 \\
& \implies b &=3 \text{ or, } 6 
\end{array}

From (3) we get, 
$$ a=6,\text{ if } b=6$$
$$ a=3,\text{ if } b=3$$

Answer (score 2):

From
$$(3\sqrt5)^2=a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=\frac14(ab)^2-2ab$$
$$\iff (ab)^2-8ab-180=0\iff(ab-18)(ab+10)=0$$
we find $ab=18$ or $-10$.  Hence $a+b=9$. Now consider $a$ and $b$ as the solutions of
 $$x^2-9x+18=0\iff(x-3)(x-6)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote by $a,b$ the sides of the rectangle. Since the area is equal to the perimeter we have that

$$ab=2(a+b)$$ and using the information about the diagonal it is

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=3\sqrt{5}.$$ Squaring we get

$$a^2+b^2=45.$$

Thus, one has to solve the system

\begin{cases}
2a+2b &=ab\\
a^2+b^2&=45
\end{cases}

From the first equation we get $b=\dfrac{2a}{a-2}$ and subtituting in the second it is

$$a^2+\dfrac{4a^2}{(a-2)^2}=45.$$ We get

$$a^4-4a^3-37a^2+180a-180=0.$$

The integer solutions of this equation are divisors of $180.$ Since $a$ is the side of a rectangle we don't consider negative values. We see that $1$ and $2$ are not solutions but $3$ is. So we have

$$(a-3)(a^3-a^2-40a+60)=a^4-4a^3-37a^2+180a-180=0.$$ Now we work with $$a^3-a^2-40a+60$$ to find more possible solutions. We see that $6$ is a solution. And

$$a^3-a^2-40a+60=(a-6)(a^2+5a-10).$$ Thus

$$a^4-4a^3-37a^2+180a-180=(a-3)(a-6)(a^2+5a-10)=0.$$

So $$(a,b)=(3,6)\:\text{and}\: (a,b)=(6,3)$$ are integer solutions of the problem.

Now we consider the equation $a^2+5a-10=0.$ It has a positive solution which is $$\dfrac{\sqrt{65}-5}{2}.$$ Since

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{65}-5}{\dfrac{\sqrt{65}-5}{2}-2}<0$$ this doesn't give a solution to the problem.

Comment: The part where I got stuck was when I substituted a = 2b/(b-2) from the first equation into the second equation. I get a 4th degree equation which I'm not able to solve

Comment: If we have to put and check integer factors, it isn't hard to see $a=6$ and $b=3$ from the beginning.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Factoring the equation using integer roots allow us to see if there are non-integer solutions.